# Cocos2d-x setDesignResolutionSize Issue

Tags: android, border, cocos2d-x, scale

I've looked at a few articles about auto-scaling android apps with cocos2d-x.
They call a function named "setDesignResolutionSize" it asks for width, height, and a policy.
The policies are things like kResolutionShowAll, kResolutionNoBorder etc. However, I'm using cocos2d-x 2.0.1 I believe and this function only wants height and width, no policy. How can I auto scale with out clipping the borders out?

Answer (score 0):

try updating to 2.2.1, it surely wants a policy, and kResolutionFixedHeight/Width are added which are much better choices in most cases. Take a look at http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support